# How to Perform WHERE NOT IN for Database column containing multiple values in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i perform a WHERE NOT IN Condition when the database column as well as the check condition have multiple values in it.

**I want to set the status of user to 1, if he doesn't belong to the excludedUserGroups**

User Status Table :- user_status

```
+---------+--------+
| user_id | status |
+=========+========+
| 1       | 1      |
+---------+--------+
```

User Table :- user

```
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| user_id | user_group_id | secondary_group_ids |
+=========+===============+=====================+
| 1       | 4             | 2,8,9               |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Variables:-

```
$excludeUsergroups = "8,7,12"
$finalExcludeUsergroups = implode(",", $excludeUsergroups);
```

Query i want to perform is :-

```sql
Update user_status us 
    LEFT JOIN user u ON us.user = u.user 
    SET us.status = 1
    WHERE (u.user_group_id NOT IN (". $finalExcludeUsergroups . ") AND u.secondary_group_ids NOT IN (" . $finalExcludeUsergroups . "))
```

**Now the issue is that, both u.secondary_group_ids and $finalExcludedUsergroups have multiple values, its giving error on checks for that second NOT IN.**

**It performs checks for user_group_id as it contains only 1 value, but when it goes to secondary_groups_ids it fails**

How can i perform the second NOT IN where it checks for each value of secondary_group_ids and checks it with $finalExcludedUsergroups

**Update**
I tested with FIND_IN_SET , however it doesn't work, as FIND_IN_SET checks for a string from the list of strings `FIND_IN_SET(string, string_list)`

But in my case i want to check a list of strings from the list of strings, which isn't possible with FIND_IN_LIST.

Comment: I would recommend normalizing your data model. Each value in the secondary group should be stored on a separate row, in a separate table. Then, the problem gets much simpler to solve.

Comment: That's why we use "database normalization": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: yaa true, however i can't do that in this case, i am using a framework which follows this structure

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set   Use the `FIND_IN_SET` for the second clause. I'm assuming the data is seperated by comma?

Comment: @floGalen I cam across that FIND_IN_SET method in various answers, but didn't understood how it can work in this scenario. I have never used it before, looked into the mysql documentation but didn't understood it.

Comment: I'm busy right now, but I'll answer you later with an example :)

Comment: @floGalen Thankyou very much, i will be waiting, i did had a quick watch over it again and found that FIND_IN_SET() takes two parameter, so i don't understand whether both parameter can accept the multiple values with commas or not.

Comment: Fix the data; storing mutiple values as delimited string is bad practice for dozens of reasons.

Comment: @MatBailie Yaa i understand that, but can't help it, as its based on a framework and it uses that as a core functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i achieved what i wanted to do through a foreach loop, i looped through the $finalExcludeUsergroups and created an array of the FIND_IN_SET and than included it in the query .

```
foreach ($excludeUsergroups as $usergroup)
        {
            $statusJoiner[] = 'FIND_IN_SET(' . $db->quote($usergroup) .' , user.secondary_group_ids) = 0';
        }
```

and than i joined them through AND condition

```
if (!empty($statusJoiner))
        {
            //Joiner for hit part
            $Joiner = ' AND ';
            $statusFinalJoiner = implode($Joiner,$statusJoiner);
        }
```

and than the query goes like this :-

```
Update user_status us 
    LEFT JOIN user u ON us.user = u.user 
    SET us.status = 1
    WHERE (u.user_group_id NOT IN (". $finalExcludeUsergroups . ") AND " . $statusFinalJoiner . ")
```

That's it, it worked out :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use MySql `NOT REGEXP` [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp) and the regular expression `/(^|\,)3($|\,)/`

```
$sql = "UPDATE user_status us 
LEFT JOIN user u ON us.user = u.user 
SET us.status = 1 
WHERE (u.user_group_id NOT REGEXP '(^|\,):id($|,)' 
AND u.secondary_group_ids NOT REGEXP '(^|\,):id($|,)')";
```

set your `:id` parameter to `$finalExcludeUsergroups`,
I would show example of how but don't know if you're using mysqli, pdo, a framework, etc

Break down of the regular expression:

- the group `(^|\,)` will match the start of the string or a comma
- `3` will match the id you're looking for (for the code I'd use a parameter here)
- the group `($|\,)` will match the end of a string or a comma

Comment: So are you saying that if I have a string '8,9,14' and I use your regular expression 
replacing :id with (say) '9,11,20,22', the result will be "false" (because 9 exists in both strings), while if I replace :id with '10,11,12,20' result will be "true" (no numbers in common)?  I'd like to see that demonstrated, because I believe, in my world at least, regular expressions don't work that way!  Maybe you've overlooked the "many-to-many" requirement in the question?

Comment: I thought you were trying to test against single id value, you wouldn't replace `:id` with anything you'd bind a value to the parameter, if you want to test against multiple values instead of passing value `"8,9,14"` pass value `"(8|9|14)"` and it will work

Comment: I'm not the OP! I just don't quite see how your proposed solution would work. The requirement is to check if any number in a comma-separated string matches any number in a second comma-separated string.  I know a bit about regexes but I don't see any special magic sauce in what you've suggested that would achieve that kind of matching. I've tried it out using a regex testing site and couldn't get the desired result. Am I missing something!

Comment: @user9601310 I recommend making your own question with your own specifics

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by your issue and wondered if a simple User Defined Function might help, so prepared the example below. If you create the function in your DB, you should be able to pass your two "comma separated value" strings to it inside your query to see if any groups are shared.  As you'll notice, I've named it for the negative case (i.e. Disjoint) as I couldn't quickly think of a suitable short name to express the positive case (i.e. Sets_have_one_or_more_elements_in_common seems a bit long!).

Hopefully someone may find this useful at some point!

```
/*
    MySQL Function to determine whether two comma-separated strings
    supplied as parameters share any common elements.
    
    Example Usage: 
    SELECT SETS_ARE_DISJOINT('8,7,12', '2,8,9'); --> False - shared entry = 8
    SELECT SETS_ARE_DISJOINT('7,12', '2,8,9');   --> True  - no shared entries
    
*/
CREATE FUNCTION SETS_ARE_DISJOINT(csv1 TEXT, csv2 TEXT)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE Occurrences INT;
    DECLARE myValue TEXT;
    SET Occurrences = LENGTH(TRIM(csv1)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(csv1), ',', ''));
Loop1:
    WHILE Occurrences > 0 DO
        SET myValue = SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv1, ',', 1);
        IF (myValue != '') THEN
            IF FIND_IN_SET(myValue , csv2) > 0 THEN
               RETURN FALSE;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            LEAVE Loop1; 
        END IF;
        SET Occurrences = LENGTH(TRIM(csv1)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(csv1), ',', ''));
        IF (Occurrences = 0) THEN 
            LEAVE Loop1; 
        END IF;
        SET csv1 = SUBSTRING(csv1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv1, ',', 1)) + 2);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
```